# Spring Cloud Netflix Feign - Error 405 Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-cloud, netflix-feign, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-feign

I'm trying to build up a REST client using Feign for my web-service.
The web-service is built with Spring 4, with an xml beans configuration.

The project is built with Maven and structured using sub-modules

```
foo-api
--- foo-api-client
------ src/main/java/foo/client
--------- FooClientFactory.java
------ pom.xml
--- foo-api-shared
------ src/main/java/foo/shared
--------- FooClient.java
------ pom.xml
--- foo-api-service
------ src/main
--------- /java/foo/service
------------ /config
--------------- FeignConfiguration.java
------------ /controller
--------------- FooController.java
--------- /webapp/WEB-INF
------------ spring.xml
------------ web.xml
--- pom.xml
```

To enable the Feign clients I have created an annotated class enabled on the Spring xml configuration.

**spring.xml**

```
...

<context:component-scan base-package="foo.service"/>

<context:annotation-config/>

<bean class="foo.service.config.FeignConfiguration" />

...
```

**FeignConfiguration.java**

```
package foo.service.config;

import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.EnableFeignClients;

@EnableFeignClients
public class FeignConfiguration {
}
```

Then I created a Feign client and configured using annotations

**FooClient.java**

```
package foo.shared;

import feign.Headers;
import feign.RequestLine;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.FeignClient;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;

@FeignClient("foo")
public interface FooClient {

    @RequestLine("GET /foo/v2/{id}")
    @Headers("Accept: " + MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    Object get(@PathVariable("id") String id);

}
```

The API controller implements the Feign client as follows

**FooController.java**

```
package foo.service.controller;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/foo")
public class FooController implements FooClient {

    @Override
    @RequestMapping(value = "/v2/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody Object get(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
        ...
    }

    ...

}
```

The foo-api-client module jar is used as a dependency by external clients to contact the foo-api-service REST service. To allow those clients to easy use the api, a factory class has been created to generate an instance of FooClient.

**FooClientFactory.java**

```
package foo.client;

import foo.shared.FooClient;
import feign.Feign;
import feign.jackson.JacksonDecoder;
import feign.jackson.JacksonEncoder;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class FooClientFactory {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public static final String SERVER_URL_PROPERTY = "foo.api.url";

    public FooClient build() {
        return Feign.builder()
                .encoder(new JacksonEncoder())
                .decoder(new JacksonDecoder())
                .target(FooClient.class, env.getProperty(SERVER_URL_PROPERTY));
    }

}
```

**PROBLEM**
When the external client performs a request to the foo web-service using the FooClientFactory `fooClientFactory.build().get("id");` a 405 error is returned.
Here is the response log on the client console:

```
ERROR [http-nio-8091-exec-1] --- [dispatcherServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is feign.FeignException: status 405 reading FooClient#get(String); content:
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 405 Request method &apos;POST&apos; not supported</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 405</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /foo/v2/{id}. Reason:
<pre>    Request method &apos;POST&apos; not supported</pre></p><hr><a href="http://eclipse.org/jetty">Powered by Jetty:// 9.3.7.v20160115</a><hr/>

</body>
</html>
] with root cause
feign.FeignException: status 405 reading FooClient#getOrder(String); content:
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 405 Request method &apos;POST&apos; not supported</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 405</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /foo/v2/{id}. Reason:
<pre>    Request method &apos;POST&apos; not supported</pre></p><hr><a href="http://eclipse.org/jetty">Powered by Jetty:// 9.3.7.v20160115</a><hr/>

</body>
</html>
```

I searched for this kind of issue around stackoverflow and other blogs but I've not been able to understand what's wrong with the whole setup.

Any idea?

Thanks,
Andrea

Comment: Either you use spring Cloud with spring boot, or you use vanilla Netflix feign. Currently there is no mix and match.

Comment: Looking at your code besides the @EnableFeignClients you are using vanilla feign and therefore spring MVC annotations won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I see two "foo" in the paths.

`@FeignClient("foo")` and `@RequestLine("GET /foo/v2/{id}")`

which makes the path as `/foo/foo/v2/{id}`, however your call should be to `/foo/v2/{id}`.

Can you please try by removing on "/foo"